# testing Page<> with BDDMockito.given spring

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA query like this:

```
Page<Journey> findByDriverId(Long UserId, Pageable pageable);
```

And this is what I wrote in Test method:

```
@Mock
private JourneyDao dao;

@InjectMock
private JourneyService journeyService;

List<Journey> journeys = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<=1; i++) {
            Journey journey = new Journey();
            journey.setDriverId(1L);
            journey.setUsername("mike");
            journey.setJourneyId("100"+i);
            journeys.add(journey);
        }
Page<Journey> journeyPage = new PageImpl<>(journeys);
given(this.dao.findByDriverId(1L, PageRequest.of(0, 2))).willReturn(journeyPage);
ResponseDto responseDto = this.journeyService.getJourneyOfUser(1L, 0, 10);
```

And this is the service method, which I am trying to test.

```
public ResponseDto getJourneyOfUser(Long userId, int page, int length) throws Exception {
    Page<Journey> journeyPage = this.dao.findByDriverId(userId,
                PageRequest.of(page, length));
    List<Journey> journeys = journeyPage.getContent();
    // and then mapping this to the responseDto by filtering out some unnecessary content
}
```

When I run the test case, I get NullPointerException. Because when service method is called from test case method, and when the service executes the query, it gives null.

Why is it happening? And how can I write such test cases in future?

Stacktrace:

```
Line: 459 (JourneyService.java) - Page<Journey> journeyPage = this.dao.findByDriverId(userId,
                    PageRequest.of(page, length));

Line 77 (JourneyServiceTest.java) - ResponseDto responseDto = this.journeyService.getJourneyOfUser(1L, 0, 10);

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.app.first.backend.service.JourneyService.getJourneyOfUser(JourneyService.java:459)
    at com.app.first.backend.service.JourneyServiceTest.getUserJourney(JourneyServiceTest.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:78)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:84)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: share a portion of the stack trace leading to the exception, I think that would help.

Comment: @CholNhial Added the stacktrace

Comment: Looks like the cause might be the dao. maybe it's not loaded. do you have `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` above the unit test class?

Comment: I ran the debugger mode and it shows that dao is loaded. Yes, I have that annotation above my class.

Comment: Did you check the service as well? look at line `Line: 459 (JourneyService.java)` find out that the dao in the service is loaded. I'm just wondering whether you are missing an annotation above the test class.

Comment: The api is working fine otherwise. And I haven't missed any annotations, I checked that a lot of times

Comment: It onlys throws this exception when running test case. The api flow works fine, I get the desired data.

Comment: I am guessing there's something wrong here maybe? - `Page<Journey> journeyPage = new PageImpl<>(journeys);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163524/discussion-between-chol-nhial-and-nirvair).